# How to join 2 tables from different databases in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using python/SQLAlchemy to extract data from MySQL databases. I have 2 different hosts, each one with a database, and I need to join 2 tables (one in each host/database). How can I do it?

I'm reading [this documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html) but I couldn't get any straightforward help. Connecting to one database is as simple as:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host/database')
```

But I'm not sure how I can work with two engines.

Anybody? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general you cannot join between two separate databases, esp. if they're not even in the same server. On the other hand some DBMS have some kinds of foreign table systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) as the glue between the two databases. For example,

```
import config
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as SA

engine_postgresql = SA.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://{u}:{p}@{h}/{d}'.format(
    u=PGUSER, p=PGPASS, h=PGHOST, d='pgtest'))
engine_mysql = SA.create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{u}:{p}@{h}/{d}'.format(
    u=MYUSER, p=MYPASS, h=MYHOST, d='mytest'))

sql = 'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tableA'
df1 = pd.read_sql(sql, con=engine_postgresql)
sql = 'SELECT col1, col2, col4 FROM tableB'
df2 = pd.read_sql(sql2, con=engine_mysql)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['col1', 'col2'])
```

[`pd.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) passes an SQL query to the database and returns a DataFrame.
[pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) joins the two DataFrames and returns a DataFrame.

DataFrames can also be inserted into databases as tables using the [`to_sql` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). For example,

```
result.to_sql('tablename', engine_postgresql, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks!